Scala: Type error not detected in "contains" method
I have this test code:
object Main:

  trait X0
  class X1(name: String) extends X0
  class X2(name: String) extends X1(name)

  {
    val seq = Seq[X1]()

    seq.contains(3.1415926)  //compiles
    seq.contains("a") //compiles
    seq.contains(X1("a"): X0) //compiles
    seq.contains(X1("a"))
    seq.contains(X2("a"))
  }

  {
    case class MySeq[A]():
      def contains[A1 <: A](a: A1): Boolean = false

    val seq = MySeq[X1]()

    seq.contains(3.1415926) // does not compile
    seq.contains("a")  // does not compile
    seq.contains(X1("a"): X0)  // does not compile
    seq.contains(X1("a"))
    seq.contains(X2("a"))
  }

The signature of “contains” of Seq is:
def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean
Beause of this, checking for the existence of a double, a string, or type X0 is allowed.
If the signature was changed to:
def contains[A1 <: A](elem: A1): Boolean
as I do in the MySeq class, then testing with these invalid types is not possible, the code does not compile, which seems like the proper behavior.
Is this a bug?
Thank you.
These statements should not compile:
seq.contains(3.1415926)
seq.contains("a")
seq.contains(X1("a"): X0) 


Also asked in the scala-users Discourse: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/type-error-not-detected-in-contains-method/9992
